# How to model relationships between sets of nodes

Tags: neo4j, relationship, graph-databases

I am currently looking at modelling tertiary courses and other such entities (MATH101, BIOL360, BSc etc.), and one of the options we're looking at is graph databases. I am not familiar with graph databases, other than in theory.

One of the things I am trying to model is requirements, for example "MATH201 requires the student previously completed MATH101". That one seems easy - I can create a vertex between the two. Others are more complicated: "Bachelor of Computer Science requires 40 points at 200 level or higher in science papers".

What I'd like to do here is name a bunch of sets, *a la* [Neo4J Labels](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/introduction/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-neo4j-labels), then create a relationship from one of the nodes to the *set* of nodes described in the labels, but I can't see a way to do this. Is this something that's possible in graph databasing engines, or am I basically running down [an XY path](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and should be doing something else entirely?

I've tagged Neo4J because I'm leaning towards it as (from what I can tell) it's the most widely known/used graph dbms, but I'm open to solutions in other databases too (in fact, if it's possible in the very new SQL Server offering, that would probably be ideal as other infrastructure is on that).

Comment: Sounds like you need an intermediate node (a :Requirement node?) that connects to the multiple nodes and encapsulates some kind of logic that applies to the grouping.

Comment: It would help to know the purpose of this graph. Is this meant to be more of a descriptive graph of courses, requirements, and degrees? Or is this meant to be a tool that, provided either outside input or existing graph data (if you're storing students and fulfilled requirements), reports back if the student has met the conditions for a degree, and if not what more is needed to fulfill those conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the fist case, I think you can make a `:REQUIREMENT` relationship between "MATH201" and "MATH101".

In the second case you can make a `:REQUIREMENT` relationship between "Bachelor of Computer Science" node and an intermediate node to group all science papers, as in the image below. Also, you can put some extra properties in the relationship to what type of requirement the course has:

[image: Sample data model]

Comment: Thanks - sorry it's taken a while, I haven't been able to give this problem much time lately. This pointed me towards a new bit of graph databases I didn't know about before (querying comparing values on relationships to values on nodes), so you've definitely educated me :)