# Returning sets of lists in graph databases

Tags: neo4j, nested-lists

This is a follow-on question from [How to model relationships between sets of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49625522/781965). I'll repeat the blurb in case that question gets removed or changed substantially:

I am currently looking at modelling tertiary courses and other such entities (MATH101, BIOL360, BSc etc.), and one of the options we're looking at is graph databases. I am not familiar with graph databases, other than in theory.

One of the use cases for this database is to query possible pathways through the courses; for example, answering the question "what minimum combinations of courses are valid to fulfill the requirements to receive a Bachelor of Science in Computer Science with Honours?". Some of the requirements will be simple (the qualification requires you've done Comp101, Math101 and Comp201) and some will provide options (require you've done 80 points of papers classified as "science" papers at the 100 level or above).

I found [neo4j lists](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/) which I thought were really promising, but what I really seem to want is to be able to return a list of lists, where each component list represents a single potential pathway. I don't see a way to generate such a list of lists though, so I'm guessing I've got something wrong at the conceptual level.

One way I could do this is have a loop that looks at the qualification node, grabs one possible combination of nodes, recursively fulfills the requirements of that node, and then moves onto the next possible combination. As a database developer, the idea of using a loop for what is clearly theoretically solvable as a set-based operation is the kind of thing that keeps me from sleeping easily at night, so I will go to great lengths to avoid such an abomination. **How can I construct a query to build such a set of sets?**

Again, I've tagged Neo4J because I'm leaning towards it as (from what I can tell) it's the most widely known/used graph dbms (and i've had quite an elegant solution to my previous question that works in that), but I'm open to solutions in other databases too (in fact, if it's possible in the very new SQL Server offering, that would probably be ideal as other infrastructure is on that).

Comment: Actually, I'm considering deleting this as I'm now not entirely convinced that it is even conceptually possible to achieve this without recursion or loops...

Comment: I don't think the use of recursion or looping is necessary, and the use of lists is probably not the right approach either. It seems to me that you just need a good graph-oriented data model (that makes good use of relationships and takes advantage of indexing to start queries).

Comment: The list-of-lists requirement here sounds more like output. You can use `collect()` to collect things as lists in your query, and depending on the query, you can use `collect()` again on the collections. I think it's more important though to get a good model for this, including ways to express OR logic for forking requirements.

Comment: You may actually need more than a graph database to solve this problem. Objectivity/DB is an object-oriented database with a full set of graph database capabilities. The advantage it has over graph databases is its ability to handle data that is considerably more complex that nodes and edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recap my comments: The use of recursion or looping should be unnecessary, and the use of lists is probably not the right approach either. You should just use a good graph-oriented data model (that makes good use of relationships and takes advantage of indexing to start queries).

At risk of going overboard to make this point, the query below uses a fairly straightforward data model to construct a portion of the graph for a school:

```
CREATE
  (sci:Area {name: 'Science'}),
  (hum:Area {name: 'Humanities'}),

  (bio:Department {name: 'Biology'})-[:IN_AREA]->(sci),
  (phy:Department {name: 'Physics'})-[:IN_AREA]->(sci),
  (che:Department {name: 'Chemistry'})-[:IN_AREA]->(sci),
  (eng:Department {name: 'English'})-[:IN_AREA]->(hum),
  (his:Department {name: 'History'})-[:IN_AREA]->(hum),
  (soc:Department {name: 'Sociology'})-[:IN_AREA]->(hum),

  (bioMaj:Major {name: 'Biology'})-[:IN_DEPT]->(bio),
  (phyMaj:Major {name: 'Physics'})-[:IN_DEPT]->(phy),

  (bio101:Course {id: 'Bio101', name: 'Introductory Biology', level: 101, credits: 3})   -[:IN_DEPT]->(bio),
  (che101:Course {id: 'Chem101', name: 'Introductory Chemistry', level: 101, credits: 4})-[:IN_DEPT]->(che),
  (phy101:Course {id: 'Phys101', name: 'Newtonian Physics', level: 101, credits: 5})     -[:IN_DEPT]->(phy),
  (phy201:Course {id: 'Phys201', name: 'Mechanics', level: 201, credits: 4})             -[:IN_DEPT]->(phy),
  (phy202:Course {id: 'Phys202', name: 'Elec & Mag', level: 202, credits: 4})            -[:IN_DEPT]->(phy),
  (eng101:Course {id: 'Eng101', name: 'Intro to Poetry', level: 101, credits: 3})        -[:IN_DEPT]->(eng),
  (eng102:Course {id: 'Eng102', name: 'Intro to Drama', level: 102, credits: 3})         -[:IN_DEPT]->(eng),
  (eng103:Course {id: 'Eng103', name: 'Intro to Fiction', level: 103, credits: 3})       -[:IN_DEPT]->(eng),
  (eng202:Course {id: 'Eng201', name: 'Medieval Literature', level: 201, credits: 4})    -[:IN_DEPT]->(eng),
  (his100:Course {id: 'Hist100', name: 'Global History', level: 100, credits: 3})        -[:IN_DEPT]->(his),
  (soc100:Course {id: 'Soc100', name: 'Intro to Sociology', level: 100, credits: 3})     -[:IN_DEPT]->(soc),

  (fred:Student {id: 123456, name: 'Fred Smith'})-[:HAS_MAJOR]->(bioMaj),
  (sue:Student  {id: 987654, name: 'Sue Jones'})-[:HAS_MAJOR]->(phyMaj),

  (fred)-[:ENROLLED_IN {year: 2017, term: 1, grade: 3.73}]->(bio101),
  (fred)-[:ENROLLED_IN {year: 2017, term: 1, grade: 3.62}]->(eng101),
  (fred)-[:ENROLLED_IN {year: 2017, term: 2, grade: 3.55}]->(che101),
  (fred)-[:ENROLLED_IN {year: 2017, term: 2, grade: 2.95}]->(eng102),
  (fred)-[:ENROLLED_IN {year: 2018, term: 1, grade: 3.13}]->(eng202),
  (fred)-[:ENROLLED_IN {year: 2018, term: 1, grade: 3.68}]->(phy101),
  (sue) -[:ENROLLED_IN {year: 2017, term: 1, grade: 3.55}]->(che101),
  (sue) -[:ENROLLED_IN {year: 2017, term: 1, grade: 3.66}]->(eng101),
  (sue) -[:ENROLLED_IN {year: 2017, term: 2, grade: 3.77}]->(phy201),
  (sue) -[:ENROLLED_IN {year: 2017, term: 2, grade: 3.44}]->(soc100),
  (sue) -[:ENROLLED_IN {year: 2018, term: 1, grade: 3.33}]->(eng202),
  (sue) -[:ENROLLED_IN {year: 2018, term: 1, grade: 3.22}]->(phy101);
```

Suppose there is a requirement that all Science majors must get a grade of 3.0+ in 3 Humanities courses, and at least one of those Humanities courses must be at the 200+ level.

We can find all Science students that have satisfied that requirement (e.g., `Sue Jones`) this way:

```
MATCH (a1:Area)<-[:IN_AREA]-()<-[:IN_DEPT]-()<-[:HAS_MAJOR]-(student)-[e:ENROLLED_IN]->(course)-[:IN_DEPT]->()-[:IN_AREA]->(a2:Area)
WHERE a1.name = 'Science' AND a2.name = 'Humanities' AND e.grade >= 3.0
WITH student, COLLECT(course) AS courses
WHERE SIZE(courses) >= 3 AND ANY(c IN courses WHERE c.level >= 200)
RETURN student;
```

Conversely, we can find all Science students that not yet satisfied that requirement (e.g., `Fred Smith`) in the following way. (Below, if the `OPTIONAL MATCH` and its `WHERE` fail to find a match, `courses` would be an empty collection).

```
MATCH (a1:Area)<-[:IN_AREA]-()<-[:IN_DEPT]-()<-[:HAS_MAJOR]-(student)
WHERE a1.name = 'Science'
OPTIONAL MATCH (student)-[e:ENROLLED_IN]->(course)-[:IN_DEPT]->()-[:IN_AREA]->(a2:Area)
WHERE a2.name = 'Humanities' AND e.grade >= 3.0
WITH student, COLLECT(course) AS courses
WHERE SIZE(courses) < 3 OR NONE(c IN courses WHERE c.level >= 200)
RETURN student;
```

Comment: This is phenomenal, thank you, and once again my mind has been slightly blown by the different ways of thinking in graphs compared to relational. I am going to have to take a bit of time to digest this, so I'll accept once I've finished that process :)